# ThreadUsafe passing object in context of spring boot jersey application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jersey

I have a simple REST Spring Boot Jersey app. I experience unpredicted behavior, most likely caused by thread-unsafe design. I need help finding the problem, as it only reproduces in prod under heavy load. The nature of the problem is that sometimes data sent by one user is being written to DB with another `userId` or sometimes I get NPE when I try access `User` object. User is a simple POJO.

Because of the nature of my clients every request is authenticated. There are no sessions, cookies, tokens in between requests. Every request from a client contains login, password and device IMEI.

I authenticate users inside `AuthorizationRequestFilter`, check that user/pass and imei are correct and add authenticated User object into `requestContext`.

`AuthorizationRequestFilter` looks like this:

```
@Component
@PreMatching
public class AuthorizationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        String auth = requestContext.getHeaderString(HEADER_PARAM_AUTHORIZATION;
        String imei = requestContext.getHeaderString(HEADER_PARAM_IMEI);
        Optional<User> user;
        try {
            user = userRepository.get(auth, imei); // Check if such user with such device exists
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            user = Optional.empty();
        }
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            requestContext.setProperty(User.PROPERTY_NAME, user.get());

            log.debug("User {} is authorized and goes to {}",
                    user.get().getId(),
                    requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());

        } else {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response
                    .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                    .entity("Unauthorized")
                    .build());
        }
    }
}
```

Next, client, for example, is saving invoices.  I explicitly check if I get a valid instance of User from context, and assertion never fails here. Neither I get null here, everything seems to be working great. My Document controller is presented below.

```
@Component
@Path("/documents")
public class DocumentController {

    @Context
    ContainerRequestContext context;

    @Autowired
    private DocumentRepository documentRepository;

    private User getUserFromContext() {
        User user;
        try {
            user = (User) context.getProperty(User.PROPERTY_NAME);
            assert user != null;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("User in context is null!");
        } catch (ClassCastException castE) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Object in context is not User");
        }
        return user;
    }



    @PUT
    @Path("invoices")
    @Consumes("application/json;charset=utf-8")
    @Produces("application/json;charset=utf-8")
    public Response saveInvoices(ArrayList<Invoice> arr) throws InternalErrorException {
        return arr != null
            ? Response.ok().entity(documentRepository.saveInvoices(getUSerFromContext(), arr)).build()
            : Response.notModified().build();
    }

}
```

But inside `DocumentRepository` I sometimes (under heavy load) get NPE when accessing passed User, or User is not actually THE user that was sending this data, that leads to ether NPE, or data saved in DB with wrong `userId`
Here is `DocumentController`:

```
@Repository
public class MysqlDocumentsRepository  implements DocumentRepository {
...

    @Override
    public Collection<ResponseItemInvoice> saveInvoices(User user, Collection<Invoice> invoices) throws InternalErrorException {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        int userId = user.getId(); 
        try {...
```

During heavy load some client connections throw  NPE in on this line `int userId = user.getId();`. I can't explain how. And sometimes later it appears that saved invoice has wrong userId.
It is not specific to DocumentController, it happens randomly across all controllers.

Pleas help me understand and fix this problem. I think it is because I mix Spring an Jersey features inappropriately, or maybe my design is somehow else flawed.

Here is my `spring config`:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ApplicationPath("/MyServer")
public class SpringConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public SpringConfig() {
        register(AuthorizationRequestFilter.class);
        register(UserController.class);
        register(ClientController.class);
        register(DocumentController.class);
        register(MetadataController.class);
        register(ProductController.class);
        register(InternalErrorMapper.class);
    }
```

And my gradle.build

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}


apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'com.example.server.MyServerApp'
}

group = 'com.example.server.'
version = '2018.1.20-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.45'

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: The resource doesn't need to be a Spring `@Component`. When you do this, I believe that Spring will instantiate it as a singleton, but you are trying to inject a request scoped request context. Remove the `@Component`. The only time I have ever really used it is when using Spring `@Value`, where it needs to be a Spring bean. Other than that, all `@Autowired`s will still work without the resource being a Spring bean. This is supported through the Spring/Jersey integration module.

Comment: Another option is to inject the request context into the resource method _parameter_ instead of the class member